# SUMIF with a difference

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to accomplish something which in my mind seems easy but I can't write it down as a formula.

Essentially, I want to do a SUMIF however I'm rather stuck.

I have a table which I would like to lookup a value along 1 row, and where it is present I want to sum a range, this range is adjacent to the cell in the row,

For example, if the value is present in A1, SUM A5:A15, if the same value is also present in B1, SUM B5:B15 and add the two together, and so on - How do I accomplish this in one pass? I want to look along a row with over 70 values, of which there are 12 possible variables,

it may not possible, but I have a hunch it's relatively straight forward ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) - entered with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:D1="my value"; A2:D15))
```

*(use `,` it instead of `;` if that is your list separator in the region and language advanced settings)*

Comment: Thanks - this looks very close. Greatly appreciated.